# Symfony: Speed up development enviroment for frontend developers

Tags: php, performance, symfony

I'm trying to create a development enviroment for the frontend developers. As long as they don't change any php code I thought it might be a good idea do this, if possible:

1. Create a new entry point all app_frontend.php i.e., disabling the debug
2. Create a config_frontend.yml file and cache php files generation but disable twig cache as well as js and css

Is there any way to do this? I'm not sure if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many environments as you want. After all, environments are just sets of different configuration, nothing more.

This means that if you want to create a `frontend` environment, you have to do just some things:

- Create some sort of front controller that constructs `AppKernel` using `new AppKernel('frontend', false);`
- As [`AppKernel::registerContainerConfiguration()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/a7deb7b79f95aff2e9c67eb7e781aa049966dfd0/app/AppKernel.php#L46-L49) in the Symfony Standard Edition uses the environment to determine the config file to load, you have to create `app/config/config_frontend.yml` as well (or change the logic in the `AppKernel` method)
- Inside this config file, make sure you import the settings that are in common. This often means importing `app/config/config.yml`. Besides that, you can configure things how you like it. E.g.

  ```
  # app/config/config_frontend.yml
  imports:
      - { resource: config.yml }

  twig:
      cache: false
  ```

You can read more about this topic in [the Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html).

Comment: And how can I disable the regeneration of php classes? I just want twig to be regenerated, not the php

Comment: @petekaner as you disable debug in this new environment, `framework.debug` will be true and it won't touch the PHP cache.

Comment: thanks! its definetely faster than the regular dev enviroment